# Twitter Follow event not working

Tags: javascript, twitter, twitter-anywhere

Hi i tried to display a alert message after user click follow

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/twitterapi" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false" data-lang="en">Follow @twitterapi</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    !function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (!d.getElementById(id)) {
            js = d.createElement(s);
            js.id = id;
            js.src = "//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }
    }(document, "script", "twitter-wjs");</script>
<script type="text/javascipt">
    twttr.events.bind('follow', function (event) {
    alert("message");
    });
</script>
```

I didn't get the alert message.Am i doing correctly?
Can anyone help? Thanq

Comment: I am also facing same problem. Please help us.